Requirements for EV Vehicle-to-Home Support
I'm wondering what it takes for an EV to be able to be used as a home backup battery. It seems like in principle this could be relatively straight forward, but I suspect that the devil is in the details.
Does an EV have to be designed with this use case in mind -- is additional hardware required to support it? Or, is it possible to use any EV that supports Level 3 (DC high voltage) charging as a backup battery?
As an example, Enphase has announced the IQ EV Charger which seems to do exactly this, but the web page neither says "these cars are supported" or "works with any CCS EV."

I'm wondering if this question would be a better fit for DIY.SE?

Or electronics.se? I agree it's not a good fit here as it's about how to connect an external battery into a house supply, it doesn't matter if that battery has wheels.

Actually, the question is -- IMHO, at least -- about the evolution of EV features. There is a box in the EV that manages the charging of the battery, and it's not obvious to me that that box would "naturally" allow the battery to be both charged and discharged through the charging port. At the very least, it seems to me, that there must be safety issues involved that mean that the battery voltage is not present at the charge connector until the charging contactors are closed.

In addition to vehicle design issues, there are also backfeed issues. Normally an interlock is used to prevent running a generator when utility power is off without first making sure the utility power is disconnected. That is important because if you rely on "flip the main breaker" and forget to do so and someone is working on the utility lines they get zapped. EV service equipment that handles vehicle-to-home will need to manage that aspect extremely carefully.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact my solar+battery installation uses a simpler system - it feeds an emergency power socket not the whole house.  I chose to have it located near the freezer , being the most likely not-really-portable thing I'd want to power in a power cut (also the control system for the gas central heating is nearby).

I agree with @dlu - the vehicle systems are key here. While some EVs/chargers combinations allow back-feeding for grid balancing (or charging at off-peak and discharging at peak times), not all do.  A vehicle that does would appear to be a pre-requisite for the system linked i the question. Enphase may be able to answer a question about a specific model or shortlist of models

Don't forget, @dlu, that the charger (so-called) is really a power supply and the car handles charging.  It does so by negotiating a voltage and current with the power supply.  That means the connection is assured before power flows

A home capable of auxiliary power must have a separate power transfer panel to switch from the electrical grid to the auxiliary power. Auxiliary power can be solar with batteries, batteries only, power generator or power from ev batteries. With ev batteries, voltage output may differ along with the inverter covering dc to ac. The batteries must have an inverter to switch dc voltages to ac and regulate it for home use. Unless a vehicle specifies amperage, ac voltage for connection to a home, you're opening a Pandora's box of technical issues most diyers aren't familiar with.

@FDryer - maybe I didn't ask the question clearly enough, but this isn't a question about the home side of V2H systems (which presumably already "know" what they need to do, or about a DIY project on either side. What I'm hoping to learn is what's require on the vehicle side to be the 'V' in a V2H system and whether that's something that you "get for free" with a car that has CCS Level 3 (DC fast charging) capabilities or if it's something that requires additional engineering and components.

I can only guess that vehicles with ac output may be limited to a specific amperage with either 120vac or 220vac. As mentioned, vehicles are not generally designed to supply home power during an outage. Nothing is free from the standpoint of vehicles supplying auxiliary power to a home.

@FDryer - "Free" as in "the design of the CCS interface already provides the necessary support on the car side" so that all of the required support would be in the EVSE and the home side equipment necessary to support a backup battery bank.
